# Using re.sub() to find and replace multiple strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use re.sub() to replace multiple strings in a template. The template is:

```
A message from the leasing office:
Hello <<firstName>> <<lastName>>,
Please pay your balance of <<balance>> before <<date>>.
```

Where `<<firstName>>, <<lastName>>, <<balance>>, and <<date>>` are being replaced by variables `first_name, last_name, balance, date`, respectively.

I am completely lost on how to search for the specific part to replace. This is what I know:

```
for line in template_file:
line = re.sub(r'<<firsName>>', first_name, line)
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I am lost at what direction to go in from here.

Comment: You should read the complete file into a string, apply `re.sub` on it and write the resulting string to the destination file.

Comment: You really wouldn't need re.sub() for something like this. Just use `line = line.replace('<<firstName>>',first_name)` for every variable

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
template_dict = {
    'firstName': first_name,
    'lastName': last_name,
    'balance': balance,
    'date': date
}

for line in template_file:
    for variable_name in template_dict:
        line = line.replace('<<{0}>>'.format(variable_name), template_dict[variable_name])
    print(line)
```

If you can rename the variables you could use a different data structure where you could use the variable's actual name directly in the template file.

Comment: Probably want to assign that replace back to `line` I guess? Although: `line = re.sub('<<(.*?)>>', lambda m: template_dict.get(m.group(), m.group()), line)` isn't too awful

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the ping, can't believe I made such a basic error!